# SAP Despatch Report Query does not display correct results

Tags: join, sapb1

I have a SAP B1 query to check for open orders that are scheduled for dispatch
The query works, but when there is a sales order without a linked production order
That order does not appear in the list. Only orders with linked production orders appear

Can someone please help me with my query joins, so that the query result displays all the orders scheduled for dispatch that has or don't have linked production orders

```
SELECT T0.[DocNum] as 'S/O #',

T1.[ShipDate] as 'Ship Date',

T0.[CardName] as 'Sales Partner' ,

T0.[NumAtCard] as 'Cust P/O #',

T1.[U_Type] as 'Type #',

T1.[U_Prod_Order_No] as 'Prod. Ord #',

T1.[OpenQty] as 'Qty',

T1.[ItemCode] as 'Item Code',

T1.[Dscription] as 'Item Description',

T1.[U_A1WMS_Comments],      

T1.[LineTotal] as 'Row Total',

T0.[Address2] as 'Ship To Address',

T2.[Status] 


FROM 
ORDR T0  
INNER JOIN RDR1 T1 ON T0.[DocEntry] = T1.[DocEntry] 
LEFT JOIN OWOR T2 ON   T0.[DocNum]  =  T2.[OriginNum] AND  T1.[DocEntry]  =  
T2.[OriginAbs] 

WHERE 
T0.[CardCode] =  T2.[CardCode] and  
T1.[U_Prod_Order_No]  =  T2.[DocNum] and 
T1. Linestatus = 'O' and T1.[ShipDate] <= [%0]
```

Thanks
Rahul

Comment: What is [U_Prod_Order_No]? are you missing the results because this value is null or empty?

Answer (score 0):

Like Hybridzz comment said, your issue is with the U_Prod_Order_No field. If you notice in your query, in your "Where" statement, you have

`T1.[U_Prod_Order_No]  =  T2.[DocNum]`

Let's take the example where you have no production order filled out on the sales order, the `WHERE` will be populating information like `'' = null` or something like that.

The solution is probably going to be to add most of the `WHERE` statements to your `JOIN`s

```
SELECT T0.[DocNum] as 'S/O #',
T1.[ShipDate] as 'Ship Date',
T0.[CardName] as 'Sales Partner' ,
T0.[NumAtCard] as 'Cust P/O #',
T1.[U_Type] as 'Type #',
T1.[U_Prod_Order_No] as 'Prod. Ord #',
T1.[OpenQty] as 'Qty',
T1.[ItemCode] as 'Item Code',
T1.[Dscription] as 'Item Description',
T1.[U_A1WMS_Comments],      
T1.[LineTotal] as 'Row Total',
T0.[Address2] as 'Ship To Address',
T2.[Status] 

FROM 
ORDR T0  
INNER JOIN RDR1 T1 ON T0.[DocEntry] = T1.[DocEntry] 
LEFT JOIN OWOR T2 ON T0.[DocNum] = T2.[OriginNum] 
    AND T1.[DocEntry] = T2.[OriginAbs] 
    AND T0.[CardCode] = T2.[CardCode] 
    and T1.[U_Prod_Order_No] = T2.[DocNum] 

WHERE T1. Linestatus = 'O' and T1.[ShipDate] <= [%0]
```

Comment: Hi Hybridzz,  Thats for the reply. Makes sense and I missed it. It worked but when i was checking the results, I noticed I had missed a table. I added it and made the changes like you have shown, but now in my query results I am getting two rows of the same production order even though i am grouping them

Comment: There's probably something wrong with the join you added, if I had to guess. Can you edit your question to include the updated query? (It's also going to give you a result for each line on the sales order, in case you weren't expecting that).